Laravel Spatie Permissions Role based redirection
I am using laravel spatie-permissions and I created a new column in roles table, so user can assign a default page for the role. When a user logins successfully if his/her role has a default page, I want him/her to be redirected to that default page, if his/her role doesn't have a default page (empty) then he/she will be redirected to the default home page. I tried to achieve this using a middleware however it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?
Laravel: 10.48.4
PHP: 8.1.25
RedirectBasedOnRole.php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectBasedOnRole
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if ($user->roles->isNotEmpty()) {
                $defaultRoute = $user->roles->first()->default_route;
                if ($defaultRoute) {
                    return redirect()->route($defaultRoute);
                }
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}

My web.php is below:
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'role.redirect'])->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', [DashboardController::class, 'index']);

    Route::prefix('dashboard')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
        Route::get('/trades', [DashboardController::class, 'trades'])->name('dashboard.trades');
        Route::get('/orders', [DashboardController::class, 'orders'])->name('dashboard.orders');
        Route::get('/fetch.dashboard.widget.1', [DashboardController::class, 'fetchDashboardWidget1'])->name('dashboard.widget1');
        Route::get('/fetch.dashboard.widget.2', [DashboardController::class, 'fetchDashboardWidget2'])->name('dashboard.widget2');
        Route::get('/fetch.dashboard.widget.3', [DashboardController::class, 'fetchDashboardWidget3'])->name('dashboard.widget3');
        Route::get('/fetch.dashboard.widget.4', [DashboardController::class, 'fetchDashboardWidget4'])->name('dashboard.widget4');
    });

    Route::prefix('strategies')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', [StrategiesController::class, 'index'])->name('strategies.index');
        Route::get('/create', [StrategiesController::class, 'create'])->name('strategies.create');
        Route::post('/', [StrategiesController::class, 'store'])->name('strategies.store');
        Route::get('/strategy-files', [StrategiesController::class, 'strategyfiles'])->name('strategyfiles');
        Route::get('/{id}/trades', [TradesController::class, 'strategy'])->name('strategy.trades');
        Route::get('/{id}/orders', [OrdersController::class, 'strategy'])->name('strategy.orders');
        Route::get('/{id}/edit', [StrategiesController::class, 'edit'])->name('strategies.edit');
        Route::put('/{id}', [StrategiesController::class, 'update'])->name('strategies.update');
        Route::delete('/{id}', [StrategiesController::class, 'destroy'])->name('strategies.destroy');
        Route::post('/strategy-files/save', [StrategiesController::class, 'strategyfilesave'])->name('strategyfile.save');
        Route::post('/strategy-files/saveas', [StrategiesController::class, 'strategyfilesaveas'])->name('strategyfile.saveas');
        Route::post('/strategy-files/addnew', [StrategiesController::class, 'strategyfileaddnew'])->name('strategyfile.addnew');
        Route::delete('/strategy-files/{strategyfile}', [StrategiesController::class, 'strategyfiledelete'])->name('strategyfile.delete');
    });
});

When a user with the role default page strategies logins successfully, I get the below redirection and error,
This is the developer console screenshot:
enter image description here

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

The middleware runs on all requests and does not take into account if this is the first request or not so it will ALWAYS redirect to the default page (if it exists) even when visiting the default page
Can the user access other pages? if so then don't redirect unless we are on a fresh login. Maybe move this logic to the auth middleware https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/7effeb99ec1568f006ed95e60d3e7dfeed1b8160/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php#L13
